# Getting an error while linking a .so file with the NDK

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Why am I getting this error while linking a shared object file?

```
$ gcc calcicall.c -o dynamically_linked -L. libcalcimethods.so.1.0.1
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../libcygwin.a(libcmain.o):(.text+0xa9)
 undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'

You are compiling and linking it as an executable. 
Use `-shared` to compile and link it as Shared object or otherwise define main function in your program.